# Mass inserting multiple files into Redis

Tags: docker, redis, pipeline

I'm trying to mass insert multiple files of data into Redis because inserting the whole data at once, using just one file, didn't work due to it being too large.

I'm using following command to insert one file into Redis:

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

How can I insert via one command multiple files at once?
I tried `cat data.txt data1.txt (...) | redis-cli --pipe` but this threw the same "too large" error as the approach with one file.

Comment: I don't understand. If it generates an error saying the input is too large when you send `data.txt` why would you try sending that file and a second one as well - surely that will be even bigger?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make much sense to me, but I think I can show you a way to split your file into chunks using **GNU Parallel**. You give no indication of the content of your file nor of its size, but let's say it is a million lines, then I could use the command `seq 1000000` to generate output similar to your file, so I'll use `seq` to synthesise lines below.

Ok, let's imagine you have 800 lines in your file - it doesn't matter if you have millions. So we can send 800 lines into **GNU Parallel** and tell it to split it into chunks of 200 lines each, then pass each chunk through `wc -l` to count the lines:

```
# Generate 800 lines and ask GNU Parallel to send 200 lines to each of multiple processes to count them
seq 800 | parallel -N 200  --pipe wc -l
200
200
200
200
```

If the number of lines in the file is not divisible by the lines per job, the last job will get fewer lines. I added the `-k` parameter to **keep** the output in order so you can see it is the last process that gets fewer lines:

```
seq 800 | parallel -k -N 300  --pipe wc -l
300
300
200
```

TLDR; I am suggesting you run a command like the following - experiment with the value that overloads `redis-cli`

```
cat OneOrMoreBigFiles | parallel -N 1000 --pipe redis-cli --pipe
```